# web api: action parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have a simple web api but when I test it with Postman, the method parameter is null. I've looked and over other questions with similar title but I haven't found an answer.

Here is my controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Member Create([FromBody] string payload)
    {
        var s = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (payload == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(payload));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(payload);
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        return null;
    }
```

And here is my postman configuration:
[image]

In the headers tab I've added `content-type` to be `application/json`.

when I'm debugging this, the `payload` variable is allways `null` and the string `s` contains something like

```
Id = 98, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = ""
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you just put a string (no JSON) into the body?

Comment: Read this and you will where you made the mistake with the parameter binding. [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) The other mistake is that you output the task and not the result of the task when trying to read the content as a string

Comment: @Donal If I put a simple string it works. But why?

Comment: @BudaGavril check the link in my last comment and read about the use of [FromBody] attribute. that is why

Comment: @BudaGavril For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter. JSON is interpreted as a complex type. If your parameter is a string, you should just put a string into the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your string in model (object):

```
class Model
{
    public string payload {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<Member> Create([FromBody] Model model) // wrap Member in Task and add async keyword
{
    var s = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // add await here

    if (model.payload == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model.payload));
    }

    Console.WriteLine(model.payload);
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    return null;
}
```

If you don't want to use model, try to send only plain string, like `"some payload"`, do not wrap it in `json`.

Comment: but... why? I don't see the logic

Comment: @BudaGavril based on your postman the body of the request shows that you are sending a json object (complex model), not a string which is what the action expects

Comment: @BudaGavril, because `json` needs model in controller. You send `json`, not a plain `string`

Answer (score 1):

Buda,

`HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync` returns a `Task<string>`, hence the value of the `s` string.

You have to update your action to make it async:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Member> Create([FromBody] string payload)
{
    var s = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (payload == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(payload));
    }

    Console.WriteLine(payload);
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code and use await, but my s variable contains string.Empty

Comment: `s` is empty because the content stream pointer is already at the end of the stream as the framework has already read it trying to populate the parameter